# Fibonacci For loop only

Tags: java, fibonacci

hello I need some help solving a problem. I saw on here that many others have asked about Fibonacci but your solutions are incorreect for me, and my level of experience. My teacher will know that I copied because she has not gone over it. What is scanner? anyway.... So I can't figure this out.

```
public class Fib2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = 1;
        int b = 1;
        int c = (a + b);

        System.out.print(a + " ");

        System.out.print(b + " ");

        for (int i = 2; i <= 11; i++) {

            System.out.print(c + " ");

            c = (a + b);
            a = b;
            b = c;

        }
    }
}
```

so my output is this: 1 1 2 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 
I don't need the second 2, I don't know how to fix it. I have manipulated this thing to death. A second set of eyes would be nice, because I can't figure it out.

Comment: Put `c=(a+b)` before `System.out.print(c + " ")`. That's where it prints twice.

Comment: I see that now. However when I wrote it i though I was creating  a space

Answer (score 1):

You are Printing and then assigning, But you should be assigning first and then printing.

So move your `c=(a+b);` before `System.out.Println();`
and then `b=a; a=c;`

i hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I fixed it for you...you had your fib code wrong and also the reason you were getting an extra two was because you had your print statement before executing the fibonacci math. so I placed it after and now it should work.

public class fibonacci {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stubpublic class Fib2{


        int a=1;
        int b=1;
        int c=(a+b);


             System.out.print (a + " ");

             System.out.print(b + " ");

       for( int i=0; i<11; i++) {



                c=(a+b);
                  **b=a;
                  a=c;**
                  **System.out.print(c + " ");**
                 }
 }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Scanner is a class used in Java which is able to read user input, simply said. It means by using it, you can let the person write something, and then take the written information and assign it to a variable or anything you desire; so long it matches the data type.

If I scan:

```
1
```

Then I can assign this 1 to an int like i.

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 int i = sc.nextInt();
```

That code reads the next integer the person inputs, and assigns I the value.

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 11; i++) {
        //c now gets value before the print!
        c = (a + b);
        System.out.print(c + " ");
        a = b;
        b = c;

    }
```